# Retirar marcações do PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Como faço para retirar as marcações em verde das palavras e dos espaçamentos conforme a imagem abaixo do PHPStorm, pois para mim acaba ficando poluído e atrapalha no desenvolvimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer tirar aquela linha verde de algumas palavras?

Comment: acho que é esse preenchimento verde que ele quer dizer @rray

Comment: Isso... a linha verde e o preenchimento verde também... é que fugiu a palavra na hora de postar...rs rs rs

Comment: » Color & Fonts » General escolha Injected language fragment  
 e Background desativar  Fonte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146836/phpstorm-configuration-how-to-remove-background-color-on-embedded-html

Answer (score 2):

Colors & Fonts -> General. Click 'Injected language fragment' e desmarque Background checkbox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Leo Caracciolo. Acho que estamos usando versões diferentes, pois apesar de encontrar essa opção no meu tema, não desabilitou a tarja verde que mencionei. Estou usando a versão PhpStorm 2017.1.2.

Comment: Veja no PhpStorm 2017.1 Help  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/file-colors.html